# using try-except block to scrape data from twitter api

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, tweepy, try-except

I'm scraping data from twiter with using their tweet ids but some of the tweets have been deleted so my code throws an error when it gets to those tweets ids

how do I use "try-except" to just skip those tweet ids or populate the with NaN
my code below:

```
tweet_ids = twitter_archive['tweet_id']

tweet_id = []
likes = []
retweets = []

try:
    for ids in tweet_ids:
        tweet = api.get_status(ids)
        tweet_id.append(ids)
        likes.append(tweet.favorite_count)
        retweets.append(tweet.retweet_count)
except:
     #I need help with the except block
tweet_info = pd.DataFrame({'tweet_id': tweet_id, 'likes': likes, 'retweets': retweets})
```

Comment: Are you looking for `pass`?

Comment: pass? I dont undersand pls

Comment: Put `pass` in the except block. And put the `try-except` inside the loop.

Comment: Ok I’ll try that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip those tweets. You can add `try-except` inside the loop for checking tweets as a better practice. Reason to add this inside the loop is that if you create a list for the missing tweets as well, you can add the missing IDs there easily.

```py
failed_tweets = []

for ids in tweet_ids:
    try:
        tweet = api.get_status(ids)
        tweet_id.append(ids)
        likes.append(tweet.favorite_count)
        retweets.append(tweet.retweet_count)
    except:
        failed_tweets.append(ids)
```

This is not going to raise an error if tweet is not found and it will continue to loop through other tweets without a problem. At the same time, iti s going to save failed tweets to a different list called `failed_tweets`.

Comment: I’ll do that now thanks

Comment: This help but how do I get a list of the tweet_ids that failed from this pls..? @g14u

Comment: @Khola Please add an example list of tweet_ids to your original question

Comment: @Khola I updated the answer, please give it a try

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cb2QKzJPlyTTEOCOWK3_StuHALCNpetM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: so no need for "pass" again..?

Comment: @Khola There is no need for pass. pass was used because we can't leave this block empty. Now we are saving `failed_items` through the `except` block so yes.

Comment: thank you it helped alot... the code will take a while to run and my pc is low so I'll update you later how it went